# I have no idea what this code is

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, syntax

I have been looking and looking and looking everywhere and I have no idea what this piece of code is called. I pulled it from jQuery

```
( function( global, factory ) {

"use strict";

if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {

    // For CommonJS and CommonJS-like environments where a proper `window`
    // is present, execute the factory and get jQuery.
    // For environments that do not have a `window` with a `document`
    // (such as Node.js), expose a factory as module.exports.
    // This accentuates the need for the creation of a real `window`.
    // e.g. var jQuery = require("jquery")(window);
    // See ticket #14549 for more info.
    module.exports = global.document ?
        factory( global, true ) :
        function( w ) {
            if ( !w.document ) {
                throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
            }
            return factory( w );
        };
} else {
    factory( global );
}

// Pass this if window is not defined yet
} )( typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function( window, noGlobal ) {...})
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: This is a wrapper for supporting different ways of loading the script. It allows it to be used both with CommonJS-style module systems (such as in NodeJS), which have to use `exports` and `require()`, as well as in browsers by defining a global. The [UMDjs](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) project offers templates for various combinations.

Comment: Let's keep comments civil and constructive please.

Comment: Hmm. And also idk if this is me but every comment is deleted

Comment: Well, I am kind of pro https://github.com/XtremePlayzCODE

Comment: Weren't exactly useful comments in clarifying the question... anyway - moving forward...

Answer (score 2):

Could be known as a wrapped/ self invoked function. But really its no different to a function. Just a humble function that gets called on definition - without a name. Hence why, at the end of the declaration, there is a list of arguments being passed straight through.

Comment: That I can see. I want to know the name to make my own

Comment: They do not really have a specific time of name - they are, just functions.

Comment: @C.Morgan The root of the snippet is an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript), or immediately-invoked function expression. As for the use of `factory` and conditionals within that, ["Universal Module Definitions"](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) is at least one name given to the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about the syntax of the code which might look weird to you, this is what called a 'self invoked function'.

Which is a function that is being invoked right away, not declaring its's name. just invoking it.